# Is it up to me having www in my web domain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

every page domain begin with **http://** or **https://** no matter what. but in some web page there is no www after that, while others have it. Is it up to me having it or not. when can i decide that?

amazon have it http://www.amazon.com/ 
while no tumblr page haven't one http://f-l-e-u-r-d-e-l-y-s.tumblr.com/

**note:** tumblr hasn't www because it has subdomains?

Comment: Please note that "www" is **not** a part of domain name.  It's a host name.  If a domain has just a single host,  then it would not matter whether you use "www" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you indeed.
In http://www.amazon.com/, amazon.com is the domain name.
http:// or https:// define the protocol (https = secured http). It's not part of the domain name.
www is a subdomain. you may have multiple subdomains for a given domain - or no subdomain.

Comment: can i have fff.fff.www.ggg.ddd.lll.mysite.com

Comment: I suppose so, while it's rather unusual.